# INNER JOIN Need to use column value twice in results

Tags: sql, join

I've put in the requisite 2+ hours of digging and not getting an answer.

I'd like to merge 3 SQL tables, where Table A and B share a column in common, and Table B and C share a column in common--Tables A and C do not.

For example:

**Table A** - entity_list

```
entity_id | entity_name | Other, irrelevant columns
```

Example:

```
1 | Microsoft |

2 | Google    |
```

**Table B** - transaction_history

```
transaction_id | purchasing_entity | supplying_entity | other, irrelevant columns
```

Example:

```
1 | 2 | 1
```

**Table C** - transaction_details

```
transactional_id | amount_of_purchase | Other, irrelevant columns

1 | 5000000 |
```

Using INNER JOIN, I've been able to get a result where I can link `entity_name` to either `purchasing_entity` or `supplying_entity`. And then, in the results, rather than seeing the `entity_id`, I get the entity name. But I want to substitute the entity name for both purchasing and supplying entity.

My ideal results would look like this:

```
1 [transaction ID] | Microsoft | Google | 5000000
```

The closes I've come is:

```
1 [transaction ID] | Microsoft | 2 [Supplying Entity] | 5000000
```

To get there, I've done:

```
SELECT transaction_history.transaction_id,
       entity_list.entity_name, 
       transaction_history.supplying_entity, 
       transaction_details.amount_of_purchase
FROM transaction.history
INNER JOIN entity_list
ON transaction_history.purchasing_entity=entity_list.entity.id
INNER JOIN
ON transaction_history.transaction_id=transaction_details.transaction_id
```

I can't get `entity_name` to feed to both `purchasing_entity` and `supplying_entity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT h.transaction_id, h.purchasing_entity, purchaser.entity_name, h.supplying_entity, supplier.entity_name, d.amount_of_purchase

FROM transaction_history h

INNER JOIN transaction_details d 
ON h.transaction_id = d.transaction_id

INNER JOIN entity_list purchaser
ON h.purchasing_entity = purchaser.entity_id

INNER JOIN entity_list supplier
ON h.supplying_entity = supplier.entity_id
```

Comment: Didn't seem to do the trick. I get empty results.

I also tried switching to LEFT JOINs, but that left me with "null" in the two "entity_name" columns.

Comment: Are you sure values in the supplying_entity field of transaction_history table matches the values of entity_id of entity_list table? I've added supplying_entity and purchasing_entity fields in the query. Please run again to make sure that they are not null.

Comment: Thanks Abdullah, as I was working from my examples in the question to the names of my actual fields, I had made a mistake in my logic. Thanks for forcing me to double check. And thanks for the quick, helpful, and most importantly, correct, response.